# MongoDB crashes meteor unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, crash, error-code

I am trying to run a very simple meteor application on my windows 10 machine. When I start meteor, everything works perfectly, but after 10 minutes or so it crashes. It gives the following error:

```
Unexpected mongo exit code 3. Restarting.                                                                               
Unexpected mongo exit code 14. Restarting.                                                                              
Unexpected mongo exit code 14. Restarting.                                                                              
Can't start Mongo server.                                                                                               
Unspecified unrecoverable error. Exit was not clean
```

I am not sure what it means and I can not fix it. If I do a `meteor reset` it will work for another 10 minutes or so then crash again. I am running meteor 1.8.0.2.

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Does the same error appear on a newly created project that has no code added but the one generated by `meteor create` ?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38988365/meteor-unexpected-mongo-exit-code-14-restarting-cant-start-mongo-server